# How to reorder bidirectional text using fribidi

Tags: c, unicode, unicode-string, freetype, harfbuzz

I have a combined English-ASCII/ Arabic-Unicode string like :

```
متن
abc
یک
```

3 Unicode Arabic character + space + 3 ASCII English character + space + 2 Unicode Arabic character

> UTF8:"\xD9\x85\xD8\xAA\xD9\x86\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xD9\x8C\xD8\xA9"
>
> UTF16: "\xFEE3\xFE98\xFEE3\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xFBFE\xFB8F"

For Displaying text in joint form like above, my embedded devices API accepts Unicode Arabic Presentation Form B in reversed order.
Therefor I need to reorder this string to below Form:

> Reordered UTF16: "\xFB8F\xFBFE\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xFEE3\xFE98\xFEE3"

and convert it to the UTF8 Presentation Form B:

> UTF8_FormB:"\xef\xae\x8f\xef\xaf\xbe\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xef\xbb\xa6\xef\xba\x98\xef\xbb\xa3"

My question is about reordering step which reorder

> UTF16: "\xFEE3\xFE98\xFEE3\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xFBFE\xFB8F"

to

> Reordered UTF16: "\xFB8F\xFBFE\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xFEE3\xFE98\xFEE3"

I think I need to use Fribidi to do this. This is How I'm using Fribidi:

```
uint32_t                utf16Str[256]       = { 0};
uint32_t                reorderedStr[256]   = { 0};
uint16_t                rawLen              = 0;
uint16_t                utf16Len            = 0;
FriBidiCharType         pbase_dir           = FRIBIDI_TYPE_ON;
fribidi_boolean         stat;

    stat =  fribidi_log2vis(
    /* input */
    utf16Str,//UTF16: "\xFEE3\xFE98\xFEE3\x20\x31\x32\x33\x20\xFBFE\xFB8F" // یک abc متن
    utf16Len,//10
    &pbase_dir,
    /* output */
    reorderedStr,//this must be filled with reordered string.
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

But the output is exactly the same as the input. And Fribidi instead of reordering just copied input to the output.
Is there anything wrong with method Flags and such?

Comment: Please add an [MCVE]. With these snippets it is difficult (if not impossible) to test.

Comment: Also, if you really have 3 lines of input, then consider using a different function. `fribidi_log2vis(...)` **cannot** work with multiple-line inputs.

Comment: @DuckDodgers No, that's a single line text. I separated it to 3 lines because of Bidi problem in the stackoverflow input textbox. As I describe above it is :  3 Unicode Arabic character + space + 3 Asci English character + space + 2 Unicode Arabic character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was about using the wrong `pbase_dir` flag. Using the below flag

```
FriBidiCharType pbase_dir = FRIBIDI_TYPE_RTL;
```

Fribidi works fine and correctly reorders my text as expected.