# How to use fribidi with std::string?

Tags: c++, string, encoding, bidi

I'm trying to write a function that will run the fribidi algorithm on a `std::string` and return a reordered `std::string`. I hope it to be safe enough for any `std::string`, and in case something fails in the way, it can return the original `std::string`.

I saw [many examples online](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/fribidi_log2vis/cpp-fribidi_log2vis-function-examples.html) that use `std::wstring`, but I wonder whether I can avoid this conversion. Here's my attempt (I may have forgotten some includes).

```cpp
# fribidi-test.cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#define FRIBIDI_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <fribidi/fribidi.h>

std::string fribidi_str_convert(std::string string_orig) {
    std::cerr << "dbg: orig: " + string_orig + "\n";
    FriBidiChar fribidi_in_char;
    FriBidiStrIndex fribidi_len = fribidi_charset_to_unicode(
        FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
        string_orig.c_str(),
        string_orig.size(),
        &fribidi_in_char
    );
    fprintf(stderr, "len is %i\n", fribidi_len);
    // https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi#api
    // Let fribidi think about the main direction by it's own (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58166995/4935114)
    FriBidiCharType fribidi_pbase_dir = FRIBIDI_TYPE_LTR;
    // Prepare output variable
    FriBidiChar     fribidi_visual_char;
    fribidi_boolean stat = fribidi_log2vis(
        /* input */
        &fribidi_in_char,
        fribidi_len,
        &fribidi_pbase_dir,
        /* output */
        &fribidi_visual_char,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    fprintf(stderr, "stat is: %d\n", stat);
    if (stat) {
        char string_formatted_ptr;
        // Convert from fribidi unicode back to ptr
        FriBidiStrIndex new_len = fribidi_unicode_to_charset(
            FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
            &fribidi_visual_char,
            fribidi_len,
            &string_formatted_ptr
        );
        fprintf(stderr, "new_len is: %d\n", new_len);
        if (new_len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "string_formatted_ptr is: %s\n", &string_formatted_ptr);
            std::string string_formatted_out(&string_formatted_ptr, new_len);
            return string_formatted_out;
        };
    };
    return string_orig;
};

int main() {
    std::string orig = "אריק איינשטיין";
    std::cerr << "main: orig: " + orig + "\n";
    std::cerr << "main: transformed: " + fribidi_str_convert(orig) + "\n";
};
```

I compile and run it with:

```bash
g++ $(pkg-config --libs fribidi) fribidi-test.cpp -o fribidi-test && ./fribidi-test
```

My problem is that I'm getting a malformed output:

```
main: orig: ןייטשנייא קירא
dbg: orig: ןייטשנייא קירא
len is 14
stat is: 2
new_len is: 27
string_formatted_ptr is: אĐןייטשנייא קי
main: transformed: אĐןייטשנייא ק
```

That `Đ` character is not supposed to be there. What I want to get is:

```
main: orig: ןייטשנייא קירא
dbg: orig: ןייטשנייא קירא
len is 14
stat is: 2
new_len is: 27
string_formatted_ptr is: אריק איינשטיין
main: transformed: אריק איינשטיין
```

Is this related to UTF16 encoding? and the fact that the new length is 27 - almost twice as that of the original length?

Comment: `};` it's just `}`. `char string_formatted_ptr;` ?? It's _one_ character... `FriBidiChar fribidi_in_char;` This is also one character. You can't write a string to one character of memory. `#include <stdio.h>` Use `cstdio`. `I saw many examples online that use std::wstring` Where? Please post them.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added a link to the examples I saw online. I'm not sure what you mean by that `};` vs `}` typo - that code is an exact copy of what successfully compiled for me. I got other errors when I tried to use `char *string_formatter_ptr;`...

Comment: You can do `};;;;;;;;;;;;;;` if you want, the `;` is just useless. Just `}`. There are `};` in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very wrong. You can't expect to store a string into one character.
Char is a char. It is not a pointer. Not a string. Remember to compile your programs with `-fsanitize=undefined` and also check with valgrind.

```
FriBidiChar fribidi_in_char;
FriBidiStrIndex fribidi_len = fribidi_charset_to_unicode(.... 
    &fribidi_in_char
);
    char string_formatted_ptr;
    FriBidiStrIndex new_len = fribidi_unicode_to_charset(...
        &string_formatted_ptr
    );
```

Also, `};` - just use `}`. There is no (need for) `;` after `}` (in these cases).

It's `cstdio` in C++.

Prefer to `<< string << string` instead of  `<< string + string` to (I think) reduce memory allocations.

Fribidi API is bad, because I do not see how to calculate memory needed for the `charset_to_unicode`. Even the `fribidy` program - https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi/blob/cffa3047a0db9f4cd391d68bf98ce7b7425be245/bin/fribidi-main.c#L64 - just uses a constant amount of super big value. Also, fribidi program is *the* example that does not use std::wstring, because it is in C.

The following program uses a constant big buffer size like fribidi program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#define FRIBIDI_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <fribidi/fribidi.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 65000

std::string fribidi_str_convert(const std::string& string_orig) {
        std::cerr << "dbg: orig: " + string_orig + "\n";
        std::vector<FriBidiChar> fribidi_in_char(MAX_STR_LEN);
        const FriBidiStrIndex fribidi_len = fribidi_charset_to_unicode(FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8, string_orig.c_str(),
                                                                       string_orig.size(), fribidi_in_char.data());
        assert(fribidi_len < MAX_STR_LEN);
        fribidi_in_char.resize(fribidi_len);
        fprintf(stderr, "len is %i\n", fribidi_len);
        //
        FriBidiCharType fribidi_pbase_dir = FRIBIDI_TYPE_LTR;
        std::vector<FriBidiChar> fribidi_visual_char(fribidi_len + 1);
        const fribidi_boolean stat = fribidi_log2vis(fribidi_in_char.data(), fribidi_len, &fribidi_pbase_dir,
                                               fribidi_visual_char.data(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "stat is: %d\n", stat);
        //
        if (stat) {
                //
                std::string string_formatted_ptr(MAX_STR_LEN, 0);
                const FriBidiStrIndex new_len = fribidi_unicode_to_charset(FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8, fribidi_visual_char.data(),
                                                                           fribidi_len, string_formatted_ptr.data());
                assert(new_len < MAX_STR_LEN);
                string_formatted_ptr.resize(new_len);
                fprintf(stderr, "new_len is: %d\n", new_len);
                //
                return string_formatted_ptr;
        }
        return string_orig;
}

int main() {
        const std::string orig = "אריק איינשטיין";
        std::cerr << "main: orig: " << orig << "\n";
        const auto ret = fribidi_str_convert(orig);
        std::cerr << "main: transformed: " << std::setw(10 + orig.size()) << ret << "\n";
}
```

and outputs:

```
$ g++ -lfribidi 1.cpp && ./a.out 
main: orig: אריק איינשטיין
dbg: orig: אריק איינשטיין
len is 14
stat is: 2
new_len is: 27
main: transformed:           ןייטשנייא קירא
```

Knowing that `FriBidiChar` is uint32_t and fribidi internally uses UTF-32 and that `wchar_t` on Linux is UTF-32, it would be preferable to use `std::wstring` (or `wchar_t`) to know how much memory to allocate. You could also count codepoints in UTF-8 input string and then precalculate the length of UTF-8 represetation of `fribidi_visual_char` to allocate memory for `fribidi_unicode_to_charset`.

Answer (score 2):

```
FriBidiChar fribidi_in_char;

FriBidiStrIndex fribidi_len = fribidi_charset_to_unicode(
    FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
    string_orig.c_str(),
    string_orig.size(),
    &fribidi_in_char
);
```

The last parameter has to be a pointer to a buffer large enough to write the results. Due to this violation, the `fribidi_charset_to_unicode` will write its output to whatever bytes happen to be in memory after this character, which is undefined behavior. Sometimes the app might crash, sometimes it'll produce the right results, sometimes it'll produce the wrong results, and sometimes it'll erase all the files in the user's home directory. The solution to this is to simply pass `nullptr` as the output, in which case it calculates the length, but does not write.

---

Similarly:

```
FriBidiChar     fribidi_visual_char;

fribidi_boolean stat = fribidi_log2vis(
    /* input */
    &fribidi_in_char,
    fribidi_len,
    &fribidi_pbase_dir,
    /* output */
    &fribidi_visual_char, //here
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

The fourth to last parameter, `visual_str` is supposed to be a pointer to a buffer of length `fribidi_len`, but you're just passing in a pointer to a single character. Due to this violation, the `fribidi_log2vis` will write its output to whatever bytes happen to be in memory after this character, which is undefined behavior. Sometimes the app might crash, sometimes it'll produce the right results, sometimes it'll produce the wrong results, and sometimes it'll erase all the files in the user's home directory.

You need to allocate enough memory for it to do it's job:

```
std::basic_string<FriBidiChar> fribidi_visual_chars(fribidi_len+1, '\0');

fribidi_boolean stat = fribidi_log2vis(
    /* input */
    &fribidi_in_char,
    fribidi_len,
    &fribidi_pbase_dir,
    /* output */
    fribidi_visual_chars.data(), //here
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

And again with `string_formatted_ptr` and `fribidi_unicode_to_charset`.

---

At a casual glance over their API, I think what you want is this:

```
std::string fribidi_str_convert(const std::string& string_orig)
  FriBidiStrIndex fribidi_len = fribidi_charset_to_unicode(
    FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
    string_orig.c_str(),
    string_orig.size(),
    nullptr);
  std::basic_string<FriBidiChar> fribidi_visual_chars(fribidi_len+1, '\0');
  fribidi_charset_to_unicode(
    FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
    string_orig.c_str(),
    string_orig.size(),
    fribidi_visual_chars.data());

  // I'm uncertain how to calculate the length, 
  // so I assumed its the same as the input :(
  std::basic_string<FriBidiChar> fribidi_visual_char(fribidi_len+1, '\0');
  fribidi_boolean stat = fribidi_log2vis(
    /* input */
    &fribidi_in_char,
    fribidi_len,
    &fribidi_pbase_dir,
    /* output */
    fribidi_visual_char.data(),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);
  if (!stat) return string_orig;

  FriBidiStrIndex new_len = fribidi_unicode_to_charset(
        FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
        &fribidi_visual_char,
        fribidi_len,
        nullptr);
  std::string string_formatted_out(new_len+1, '\0');
  fribidi_unicode_to_charset(
        FRIBIDI_CHAR_SET_UTF8,
        &fribidi_visual_char,
        fribidi_len,
        string_formatted_out.data());
  return string_formatted_out;
}
```